# Find nearest position from a fixed position to a line joined by two GPS positions

Tags: java, gps

I want to find the nearest position from a fixed position to a line joined by two GPS positions. I have tried to illustrate it with the means of a diagram. All positions are in GPS coordinates. I want to find the ´shortest diatance from the position P to the line joined from position A and position B,i.e., the line from P makes a 90 degree on line joining A and B. 
It would be really great if you know of an existing implementation for this or an algorithm for the same. Many Thanks.
[image]

The way i was told to calculate is: 
first convert the GPS positions into cartesian coordinates. For the conversion , it uses a reference position (Q_Ref_longitude, Q_Ref_latitude).

```
x=(longitude-reflong)*π/180*r_e, r_e radius of earth
y=artanh(sin⁡(latitude))
Therefore the reference point has the Cartesian coordinates (0,artanh(sin⁡(reflat))).
conv(refp)=(0,artanh(sin⁡(reflat)))
All positions A,B, P are converted to (x,y) coordinate system
Calculation of the intercept point with reference Cartesian coordinates (x,y)∈R^2:
In the following context (vp) ⃗∈R^2 is the position vector of the P in reference Cartesian coordinates.
<a ⃗,b ⃗> is the dot product of two vectors a ⃗ and b ⃗.
(op2) ⃗  refers to position A
(op1) ⃗ refers to position B
(vp) ⃗ refers to position P
(op1) ⃗,(op2) ⃗,(vp) ⃗∈R^2

    intPoint=[(<((op2)-(op1)),((vp)-(op1))>)/(<((op2)-(op1)),((op2)-(op1))>)]*((op2)-(op1))+(op1)

The intercept point has to be transformed back into GPS coordinates with the following inverse formula:

Iconv:R^2→[-180°,180°]×[-90°,90]
longitude=x+reflong
latitude=arcsin⁡(tanh⁡(y))
```

Does someone know about this way? I tried to do this way but it gives negative values.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358022/find-the-better-intersection-of-two-moving-objects

Comment: What kind of distances are we dealing with? If short enough you can approximate AB as a straight line. If you must account for the curvature of the Earth it gets quite complicated.

Comment: @Joni: the distances are short enough in the range of less than 50 metres.

Comment: Isn't that basic triangle calcs ? You have length A-B,B-P,P-A and can calc all angles of ABPA. With length B-P, given angle at B and 90° at X you can calc X-P.

Comment: Be careful: If A,B and P are (almost) in the same line, the shortest distance will be (P,A) or (P,B), and no 90 degree line will be found to join them

Comment: @Pablo: I have updated the question with the algorithm which I am using

Comment: What's the source for that algorithm?

Comment: For short distances (below 80 deg of latitude, and asuming not to cross the datum limit)  you can ignore spherical behavior. Then it  is school mathematics. (Normal projection of a point to a line).

Answer (score 0):

Given that the distances are so short, if you are not near to a pole you can use a cheap approximation based on regular plane geometry.

The very first thing you have to do is a change of coordinate system: multiply the longitudes by the cosine of the latitude to account for the fact that degrees of longitude are shorter near the poles. Otherwise you won't get a 90° angle when calculating the projection.

After that you compute the projection of point P on the line AB like normally.

Once done, divide the longitude by the latitude to undo the coordinate change made earlier.

Here's the basic algorithm:

```
// input:
double Alat, Alng, Blat, Blng, Plat, Plng;
// output: 
double Xlat, Xlng;

// change of coordinate system
Alng *= cos(Alat * PI/180);
Blng *= cos(Blat * PI/180);
Plng *= cos(Plat * PI/180);

// compute projection
double scale = ((Blng-Alng)*(Plng-Alng)+(Blat-Alat)*(Plat-Alat)) /
               ((Blng-Alng)*(Blng-Alng)+(Blat-Alat)*(Blat-Alat));

Xlat = (1-scale)*Alat + scale*Blat;
Xlng = (1-scale)*Alng + scale*Blng;

// change to original coordinate system
Xlng /= cos(Xlat * PI/180);

return (Xlat, Xlng)
```

You could make it even cheaper by computing the cosine for only one of the latitudes; there's no big difference.

If you are near a pole or need more accurate results for whatever reason you'll have to use a more complex algorithm.

Comment: I am not computing these values near the poles. So, I can go forward with the implementation you have suggested. I have some confusion with the ur algorithm:                                  Alng *= cos(Alat * PI/180);--> Along= Along*cos(Alat*PI/180) ?? and when converting back, Xlat doesnt need to be converted?

Comment: I am not computing these values near the poles. So, I can go forward with the implementation you have suggested. I have some confusion with the ur algorithm: Alng *= cos(Alat * PI/180);--> Along= Along*cos(Alat*PI/180) ?? and when converting back, Xlat doesnt need to be converted?

Comment: Yes, `a *= b` is short for `a = a*b` in Java and other C-like languages. With this coordinate change the latitudes can stay as they are, only the longitudes are tweaked.